# Calling feature file within another feature file using tags

Tags: karate

Is there a way to call a particular scenario from a feature file within a callonce call in Karate.

Consider

**File1.feature**

@Scenario1

Scenario:
#.........

@Scenario2

Scenario:
#.............

**File2.feature**

Feature: Feature name

Background:

```
* def result = callonce read('./File1.feature@Scenario1')
```

Is this possible?